# rabbitmq.conf consumer_timeout not working in docker

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I'm trying to execute a longer task with celery, so to test I made a sample task sleep for 5 minutes and set the `rabbitmq.conf` file with a single line containing `consumer_timeout = 10000` expecting the task to fail with precondition error after 10seconds(or at least after 60 seconds as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70958499/5951165)), but it never did. The task completes after 5mins.
I can see the rabbitmq.conf file shows up on top of logs(which I think it means it loaded the file successfully??)

```
main_rabbitmq         |   Config file(s): /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
main_rabbitmq         |                   /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/10-default-guest-user.conf
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.9.13-management

# Define environment variables.
ENV RABBITMQ_USER user
ENV RABBITMQ_PASSWORD password
ENV RABBITMQ_PID_FILE /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbitmq

COPY ./myrabbit.conf /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf

ADD init.sh /init.sh
RUN chmod +x /init.sh

# Define default command
CMD ["/init.sh"]
```

The init.sh file is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30773882/5951165).

Comment: Just a guess: `consumer_timeout` may exist in both config files and your value is overriding by default `/etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/10-default-guest-user.conf` value

Comment: I checked it, it has only one line `loopback_users.guest = false`